# Difficulty Constructing an Arraylist method

Tags: java

I am trying to construct a method that will allow me to find the total cost of a number of items in an arraylist. Currently I have an arraylist full of "items." In the item class the objects have a price and a quantity found by getQuantity and getPrice. I'm trying to find the total cost of all the items in the arraylist but keep getting 5 errors. Can anyone help thanks,

EDIT: Posted the errors

```
 public double getTotalCost()
         {

            double total;
            for(int i = 0; i < cart.size; i++) // size has private access in ArrayList
            {
                total = ((cart.get(i)).getQuantity) * ((cart.get(i)).getPrice) + total; // cannot find symbol // illegal start of type// cannot find symbol // illegal start of type
            }


            return total;
         }   
    }
```

Comment: why no closing braces for getQuantity() and getPrice() etc.,

Comment: Why are you not posting the errors messages? We're terrible at reading minds you know.

Comment: also, using the += operator would make this much more readable. plus, the "total" variable isn't initialized with 0. not to mention that a "for-each" over the ArrayList would be more preferable...

Comment: Re: "I [...] keep getting 5 errors": When asking about error-messages, you should always post them. (In this case I think we can guess what they are, but you should always post them, anyway.)

Comment: Ok, I will definitively post them sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a method on a object, you always need to use parentheses. So not `cart.size` but `cart.size()`. If you do not, Java expects you are requesting a `public variable` for a object. size is a `private variable` in your List Object and therfore gives you a private access error

```
public double getTotalCost(){
  double total = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++){
    total =  ( cart.get(i).getQuantity() * cart.get(i).getPrice() ) + total;
  }
  return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing parenthesis, lots of them. Try this:

```
public double getTotalCost() {
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
        total = cart.get(i).getQuantity() * cart.get(i).getPrice() + total;
    }
    return total;
}
```

And I'm assuming that `cart` was declared using generics, something like this:

```
ArrayList<Item> cart = ...
```

Takeaway lesson: when you call a method in Java, it will *always* have parenthesis after the name, even if it doesn't receive any arguments.

Comment: `total` is a local variable, so is required to be explicitly initialized before being used.

Comment: My instance field is private ArrayList<Item> cart;

Answer (score 0):

You can get the size of an ArrayList with the `size()` method - ArrayList's `size` field is private, but the method is public and can be used instead.

Another error likely comes from trying to access the Item class's `getPrice` and `getQuantity` fields rather than the `getPrice()` and `getQuantity()` methods - another quick fix, just remember the parenthesis!

Syntactically speaking, you can probably make things a bit easier on yourself using some different syntax in your for loop (though this may be beyond your class a bit):

```
double total = 0;
for (Item i : cart) {
    total += i.getQuantity() * i.getPrice();
}
```

Some other tips: your `total` field isn't initialized to anything (though it is in the example above). This may work fine with native types (ints, floats, doubles, etc), but it'll definitely cause compiler complaints later on with non-primitive types. If in doubt, initialize them to 0 for primitives or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why everyone is bypassing the obvious for loop construct to ease this a bit. Here I use CartEntry, replace that with whatever object is in your List that has the getQuantity() and getPrice() methods on it.

```
double total = 0;
for(CartEntry entry: cart){
  total += entry.getQuantity() * entry.getPrice();
}
return total;
```

While I'm at it. I'd suggest putting an extendedPrice() method on whatever the object type is in the cart, which does the quantity * price multiplication for you.